# Symfony - authenticated anonymous user account -> convert to regular one

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am using FossUserBundle. Can I set it to described behavior (down below) or get some additional bundle?

If user is not authenticated he/she has anonymous account stored in DB. By registering he/she can convert it to regular account.

The packege exists for Django it is called lazy signup: https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup